# How to Query for data only when a tab is click in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create a tab bar similar to Reddit's where the app only loads the data when I click on a tab, i.e. Politics.

[image]

How can I use the tab bar and TabBarView such that I only load the data from firestore when I click on it similar to Reddit?

My code is as shown below:

```
class TabsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabsDemoState createState() => _TabsDemoState();
}

class _TabsDemoState extends State<TabsDemo> {
  TabController _controller;
/// this list will change according to what they prefer their interested category to be
  List<String> categories = ["All", "Politics", "USA", "World"];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return DefaultTabController(
            length: categories.length,
            child: new Scaffold(
                appBar: new AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  bottom: new TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.white70,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white30,
                    labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 3),
                    indicator: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(27),
                        color: Colors.transparent),
                    isScrollable: true,
                    tabs: List<Widget>.generate(categories.length, (int index) {
                      print(categories[0]);
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 9.0, right:9),
                        child: new Tab(
                            text: categories[index]),
                      );
                    }),

                  ),
                ),

                body: new TabBarView(
                  children: List<Widget>.generate(
                      categories.length, (int index) {
                    /// how should I fill this ?
                  }),
                )
            ))
    ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TabBar` widget has a parameter named `onTap` which will be triggered when user taps on a Tab, this parameter is a function with an input parameter which indicates the index of tab, you can load your data based on this index number, for example:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: ...,
  bottom: TabBar(
    onTap: (selectedIndex) {
      switch(selectedIndex) {
        case 0: {
          /// ... load your data here
        }
        break;
        case 1: {
          /// ... load your data here
        }
        ...
      }
    },
    tabs: [],
  ),
),
```

- onTap event get not called when you swipe tabs, if you want to handle loading data when user swipes between screens, you can add a controller for you tabs, [here is an example](https://medium.com/flutterworld/flutter-tabbar-and-tricks-4f36e06025a4)
- If loading data is time-consuming, it's better to use some kind of Async loading approaches like using BLOC library, if you're not familiar with BLOC and State Management topic, you can take a loot at [this link](https://bloclibrary.dev)

Comment: Great, I will be using the controller method to handle loading data when the user swipes between screens. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [flutter api TabBar link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html).

Sample in the above link is very clear for creating `TabBarView`.
if you have any problem comment on this answer, i will try to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I figured it out with the answer from @G3ntle_Man

Comment: you should provide the solution not some link to follow for the answer